# How to get TAPI HCALL handle?

Tags: vba, winapi, hwnd, tapi, window-handles

I want to use [`lineBlindTransfer()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735509.aspx) to blindly transfer a connected telephony call.

Here is the declaration in the documentation:

```
LONG WINAPI lineBlindTransfer(
   HCALL  hCall,
   LPCSTR lpszDestAddress,
   DWORD  dwCountryCode
);
```

I connected the call using [`tapiRequestMakeCall()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737210.aspx) function in Excel VBA:

```
Declare Function tapiRequestMakeCall Lib "tapi32.dll" _
(ByVal stNumber As String, ByVal stDummy1 As String, _
ByVal stDummy2 As String, ByVal stDummy3 As String) As Long

Sub DialNumber(Number As String)
Dim lngStatus As Long

 lngStatus = tapiRequestMakeCall(Number, "", "", "")

 If lngStatus < 0 Then
  MsgBox "Failed to dial number " & Number, vbExclamation
 End If

End Sub
```

How can I get the `HCALL` to transfer the connected call to some other number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[lineMakeCall](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Syntax C++

```
LONG WINAPI lineMakeCall(
   HLINE                  hLine,
   LPHCALL                lphCall,
   LPCSTR                 lpszDestAddress,
   DWORD                  dwCountryCode,
   LPLINECALLPARAMS const lpCallParams
);
```

> **lphCall**
>
> **Pointer to an HCALL handle**. The handle is only valid after the LINE_REPLY message is received by the application indicating that the
>   lineMakeCall function successfully completed. **Use this handle to
>   identify the call** when invoking other telephony operations on the
>   call. The application is initially the sole owner of this call. This
>   handle is void if the function returns an error (synchronously or
>   asynchronously by the reply message).

Comment: I am using TAPI 2.2 in excel vba, how to use TAPI 3.0 in excel vba ? Is that possible ??

Comment: @FahdKhan I want to say only that the call you want to transfer must to have hCall already that was assigned by function that made successfull call.

Comment: @FahdKhan it seems me that TAPI version is not important in this case...

Comment: @FahdKhan I suppose that the serach on the project code template you used will help you to find points where `hCall` assigned. And try do not rename parameters of referenced libs as you made with `tapiRequestMakeCall`.

Comment: Thank for the replies dude. But there's no method to get hCall. Can you help me with this please

Comment: @FahdKhan if you read the documentation, `lineMakeCall()` is available in TAPI 1.3 and later.

Comment: @FahdKhan Sorry... It was many years ago and almost nothing remained in my memory. There were no projects and code samples left either. I repeat - try to search on renamed variables, that may implicity act as `hCall'...

Comment: @RemyLebeau It does not matter where call handle comes from. It is present everywhere. And it is the main :)

Comment: but for this, i have to use lineInitializeEx()

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735983%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: what to do with parameters of this lineInitializeEx(), it also had a hInstance Handle instance :)

Comment: Call GetModuleHandle(NULL) to get the hInstance. VBA isn't a real good programming language to use TAPI... and better check first if your TSP supports lineBlindTransfer...

Comment: It is giving module handle rather than handle to the Call

Comment: lineInitializeEx -> HLINEAPP + device discovery -> lineOpen(device) -> HLINE -> lineMakeCall (for outbound) OR lineGetNewCalls (for existing) OR lineGetMessage (for inbound LINE_APPNEWCALL message) -> HCALL -> lineBlindTransfer